# What are the ways to implement Biometric (Fingerprint ) Authentication with Azure Ad (B2C) In React Native App (Android And IOS)

Tags: react-native, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-mobile-services

I have setup an Azure Ad Account, Having Client Id, Tenant Id , Able to Login With Clint Id For a Added Account (In A Tenant )  From My React Native App. Now I am looking for options to implement Biometric Authentication.

Please Let me know if there is any resource or information is available for the same.

I have just looked for Configure Transmit Security with Azure Active Directory B2C for password less authentication.

Looking for more to understand the flow.

Answer (score 0):

The [samples](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples?tab=readme-ov-file#multi-factor) have examples for FIDO and fingerprint.

You could use [verified credentials](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-verifiable-credentials/tree/main/B2C).

VC now includes a [face check](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2024/02/06/microsoft-entra-verified-id-introduces-face-check-in-preview/).

Or integrate with some third party via API.